# Two servers 2012 on same subnet not communicating

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012

I have a very simple network (private) setup. Two win2012 servers connected to a simple Giga switch. They both have static ip addresses (192.168.1.118, 192.168.1.119), both have same subnet mask (255.255.255.0), both have default gateways that matches their ip addresses and lastly, they both have DNS server ip addresses that matches their ip address.

My issue is, the communication is only in one directions. Why?

Comment: If they're in the same broadcast network (which they are, according to the poster) the gateway isn't relevant. If communication one way is working, it's most likely a firewall issue.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, this must be a firewall problem.

Strictly speaking, the communication can't actually be one way because a packet needs to be send and then returned, so we can rule out the possibility of a cabling fault.

It is remotely possible the issue is a driver fault relating to ARP requests, however this is HIGHLY, HIGHLY unlikely and could be elminated by communicating one way, and then immediately the other way, because the ARP table would already be set up.

Rather, what is most likely happening is that 1 host is blocking incoming connections on its firewall and only allowing outbound requests and their established/related return packets.